# Cocoa-Touch: issue looping MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have an app which has to load some data at startup, so I want to display a splash-screen animation.

I'm using the `MPMoviePlayerController` to play a m4v file.
The movie has it's background set to `[UIColor clearColor]`.
Default.png is the movie`s first frame, and also the initial view`s background image (as a `UIImageView`).

To loop the movie, I'm subscribing to it's `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification` notification and when it triggers I'm doing a `[movie play]` which restarts the movie.

Everything works almost fine.

When the movie is re-started (the 2nd loop), it plays, but once every few frames it paints the background image over it again and then re-paints the movie. This produces something close to a flicker.

It's like having this frame sequence:
`1 2 3 4 _image_ 5 6 7 8 9 _image_ 10 11 12 ..`
I've validated that it's the background image by changing it, and the repainted image is also changed.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: sounds a bit like this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/771980/sample-code-movieplayer-problem

Comment: @wkw, it's actually exactly the same problem. That post has no real answer tho :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to only happen on the simulator, it works fine on the device. I can live with that.